# variables does not change while set before calling _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(...))

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

I call a function of 1icnh smart contract named "getExpectedReturn" inside my contract's function. when I set a variable (named v1) before the call, the variable does not change but if I set a variable (named v2) after the call it works. I have no clue why it is so.
Below is a simple contract to reproduce the issue:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

contract A  {

    address internal constant ONE_INCH_ADDRESS = 0xC586BeF4a0992C495Cf22e1aeEE4E446CECDee0E;
   
    uint256 public v1 = 1;   
    uint256 public v2 = 2;
   
    event Ev1( uint256  v1, uint256  v2);

    function A1 () public {
       
        v1 = 11;  /*this does not work*/
         
 
        ONE_INCH_ADDRESS.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(
                                "getExpectedReturn(address,address,uint256,uint256,uint256)",
                                                    0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE,
                                                    0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F,
                                                    1000000000000000000, 100, 0));
        v2 = 22; /* this works*/

        emit Ev1(v1, v2); /* here v1 is 1 but should be 11 ! and v2 is 22*/
        
    }
}
```

the log of executing of function A is attached below:

```
[ { "from": "0x69A5e5e86c72aE3D57bBD25A38f63bc527176228", "topic": "0x9aa0a5ee181172acba4a8b7e3c24db463f4c218ff10a6ea1777f43817d257414", "event": "Ev1", "args": { "0": "1", "1": "22", "v1": "1", "v2": "22", "length": 2 } } ]
```

Any recommendation is welcomed.

PS1: The contract is deployed on a forked mainnet in remix. (the used addresses are on Ethereum mainnet, ETH:0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE, DAI:0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a ganache-cli bug.

Here is your [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd8b5ac3237659ee32d51811887b3ad4d860dd13aa48f85c455ad961926cb0dd8#eventlog) on mainnet and the event looks fine.

Comment: Awesome ,Thank you very much. you deployed the contract on the mainnet to find the issue, You are great!   ps: I have utilized "Truffle teams" to fork the mainnet.